# $\bigcup A$ has same cardinality as $\bigcup B$ if every member of $A$ and $B$ are infinite and has same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, if I know:

1. For every element $a\in A$, there is an element $b\in B$ which has the same cardinality as $a$, i.e. $|a| = |b|$, and also for every $b\in B$ there is an element $a\in A$ such that $|a| = |b|$.
2. Every element in $A$ has infinite cardinality, and every element in $B$ has infinite cardinality.

Can I prove $\bigcup A$ has the same cardinality as $\bigcup B$? If the answer is yes, may I please ask for a proof? If not (which surprises me), how do you slightly modify the condition on infiniteness so we can prove it?

Hints and references to existing posts or theorems are also appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What about $A=\{\mathbb Z\}$ and $B=\{\alpha+\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb R:\alpha\in[0,1)\}\subset 2^{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: Right. Thank you! Do I have hope if I add a condition that $A$ and $B$ have the same infinite cardinality?

Comment: I think that fails if you replace $A$ with the set of all infinite subsets of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Right. Thanks again. I may in trouble now and will think more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. Even if $|A|=|B|$. E.g. if $A$ is the set of all countably infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ and if $B$ is the set of all countably infinite subsets of $\Bbb R$ then $|A|=|B|=2^{\aleph_0}$. But $|\bigcup A|=|\Bbb N|=\aleph_0<2^{\aleph_0}=|\Bbb R|=|\bigcup B|.$